# Multithreading queue with std::async in an audio context

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to figure out if we are using a correct approach for multithreading lambdas with `std::async`. We are working on an audio library that takes parameters as input which might trigger the creation of objects and we need a safe way of transferring information after the creation of the object to the audio thread. The library itself doesn't own any threads, but its functions might be called from different threads.

This is the use of the class:

```
AsyncManager manager;

void calledFromParamterThread() 
{
    BigObject* object = new BigObject; // heavy lifting
    manager.executeAsync([=]
    {
        object.changeParameter();
    }
}

void calledFromAudioThread()
{
    manager.tryExecuteAllAsync();
}
```

This is the AsyncManager class:

```
class AsyncManager
{
public:
    AsyncManager()
    {
        m_futures.reserve(100);
    }

    template<class Function, class... Args>
    void executeAsync(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (m_mutex);

        m_futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::deferred, f, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    void tryExecuteAllAsync()
    {
        if (m_mutex.try_lock()) {
            for (auto& future : m_futures) {
                future.get();
            }
            m_futures.clear();
        }
    } 
private:
    std::vector<std::future<void>> m_futures;
    std::mutex m_mutex;

};
```

Since the audio thread must be lock-free, I'm using a try_lock in the audio thread, to return immediately and not cause dropouts. If that's not acquired the parameter change will be tried to apply during the next audio blog.

Comment: do you have an issue from your current approach? questions like "is this a good approach" aren't very answerable because they can be very opinionated

Comment: Your code will execute serially. Creating multiple asynchronous operations using `std::launch::deferred` policy, and then serially going over them to `.get()` is simply "sequential". There's no parallelism there in your code snippet.

Comment: That's aside the various problems in your code snippet. Please can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Use of many std::asyncs can potentially screw you over with the cost of thread creation. If your processing takes ~15 ms, consider instead using a producer consumer queue.